XML element sorting Problem while doing sorting of element
I have below xsl code which is not giving me sort on SEC_Match element:
    <xsl:template match="*[SEC]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:variable name="a" select="substring-before(@UID,'^')"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="self::SEC[$a = substring-before(following-sibling::SEC[1]/@UID,'^')]|self::SEC[$a = substring-before(preceding-sibling::SEC[1]/@UID,'^')]">
                    <xsl:for-each select="self::SEC[$a = substring-before(following-sibling::SEC[1]/@UID,'^')]|self::SEC[$a = substring-before(preceding-sibling::SEC[1]/@UID,'^')]">
                        <xsl:sort select="@STARTEFFDATE" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                        <SEC_Match>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                        </SEC_Match>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

INPUT XML:
<LEVEL2 UID="XXXX" CAPTION="CH" D="381" PRIOR="NO" MEDIA="ALL">
    <NAME>Public Health: </NAME>

    <SEC D="3-4-218" UID="ar3-4-218^XXXX" STARTEFFDATE="20171001">
        <NAME> permitted premises</NAME>
        <SBSEC D="(a)" LOC="3-4-218(a)" ANCHOR="3-4-218(a)" PERIOD="0" PRIOR="NO">
            <P> test test </P>
        </SBSEC>
    </SEC>

    <SEC D="381.986" UID="fl381.986^XXXXX" STARTEFFDATE="600"
        >
        <NAME>Medical use of marijuana</NAME>
        <SBSEC D="(1)" LOC="381.986(1)" ANCHOR="381.986(1)" PERIOD="0" PRIOR="NO">
            <P>who has agreed to assist</P>
        </SBSEC>
    </SEC>

    <SEC D="381.986" UID="fl381.986^XXXX" STARTEFFDATE="200">
        <NAME>Medical use of marijuana</NAME>
        <SBSEC D="(1)" LOC="381.986(1)" ANCHOR="381.986(1)" PERIOD="0" PRIOR="NO">
            <P> &#8220;Attractive to children&#8221;</P>
        </SBSEC>
    </SEC>

    <SEC D="381.986" UID="fl381.986^XXXX" STARTEFFDATE="800">
        <NAME>Medical use of marijuana</NAME>
        <SBSEC D="(1)" LOC="381.986(1)" ANCHOR="381.986(1)" PERIOD="0" PRIOR="NO">
            <P> &#8220;Attractive to children&#8221; means the use of any image or words</P>
        </SBSEC>
    </SEC>

    <SEC D="3-4-218" UID="ar3-4-218^XXXXX" STARTEFFDATE="20171001">
        <NAME>Permits restricted to permitted premises</NAME>
        <SBSEC D="(a)" LOC="3-4-218(a)" ANCHOR="3-4-218(a)" PERIOD="0" PRIOR="NO">
            <P>goods, dry goods, hardware, or general mercantile store. </P>
        </SBSEC>
    </SEC>

    <SEC D="381.986" UID="fl381.986^XXXXX" STARTEFFDATE="100">
        <NAME>Medical use of marijuana</NAME>
        <SBSEC D="(1)" LOC="381.986(1)" ANCHOR="381.986(1)" PERIOD="0" PRIOR="NO">
            <P>identification card, and meets the requirements of subsection (6). </P>
        </SBSEC>
    </SEC>
</LEVEL2>

Current OUTPUT XML:
<LEVEL2 UID="XXXX" CAPTION="CH" D="381" PRIOR="NO" MEDIA="ALL">
<NAME>Public Health: </NAME>
<SEC D="3-4-218" UID="ar3-4-218^XXXX" STARTEFFDATE="20171001">
    <NAME> permitted premises</NAME>
    <SBSEC D="(a)" LOC="3-4-218(a)" ANCHOR="3-4-218(a)" PERIOD="0" PRIOR="NO">
        <P> test test </P>
    </SBSEC>
</SEC>
<SEC_Match D="381.986" UID="fl381.986^XXXXX" STARTEFFDATE="600">
    <NAME>Medical use of marijuana</NAME>
    <SBSEC D="(1)" LOC="381.986(1)" ANCHOR="381.986(1)" PERIOD="0" PRIOR="NO">
        <P>who has agreed to assist</P>
    </SBSEC>
</SEC_Match>
<SEC_Match D="381.986" UID="fl381.986^XXXX" STARTEFFDATE="200">
    <NAME>Medical use of marijuana</NAME>
    <SBSEC D="(1)" LOC="381.986(1)" ANCHOR="381.986(1)" PERIOD="0" PRIOR="NO">
        <P> “Attractive to children”</P>
    </SBSEC>
</SEC_Match>
<SEC_Match D="381.986" UID="fl381.986^XXXX" STARTEFFDATE="800">
    <NAME>Medical use of marijuana</NAME>
    <SBSEC D="(1)" LOC="381.986(1)" ANCHOR="381.986(1)" PERIOD="0" PRIOR="NO">
        <P> “Attractive to children” means the use of any image or words</P>
    </SBSEC>
</SEC_Match>
<SEC D="3-4-218" UID="ar3-4-218^XXXXX" STARTEFFDATE="20171001">
    <NAME>Permits restricted to permitted premises</NAME>
    <SBSEC D="(a)" LOC="3-4-218(a)" ANCHOR="3-4-218(a)" PERIOD="0" PRIOR="NO">
        <P>goods, dry goods, hardware, or general mercantile store. </P>
    </SBSEC>
</SEC>
<SEC D="381.986" UID="fl381.986^XXXXX" STARTEFFDATE="100">
    <NAME>Medical use of marijuana</NAME>
    <SBSEC D="(1)" LOC="381.986(1)" ANCHOR="381.986(1)" PERIOD="0" PRIOR="NO">
        <P>identification card, and meets the requirements of subsection (6). </P>
    </SBSEC>
</SEC>

Expected output would be all Matching_sec should be in descending order by @STARTEFTDATE.

Sorting on self::something? That doesn't make sense, it is a single node.

@MartinHonnen How could i achive it. If not this loop. Also i cant create a second xslt. Hints will be much appriciated. Thanks!!!

Some @STARTEFFDATE have normal date values like 20171001, others have values like 100. Could you explain why?

Sorry!!! I was added 100 600 and 800 to see if it really work or not. I did not mentioned it.
